# Get data from external api to google sheets using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get data from here https://apiv2.avirato.com/apiBookingSwagger#/ to google sheets using rest api. I've written the following code till now but don't have any idea how to continue. Any kind of help would be appreciated cuz I'm new to apps script and api's.

```
function myFunction() {
 
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
 
 mainSheet.getRange('A1').clear();
 
 var URL_STRING = "https://apiv2.avirato.com/apiBookingSwagger#/availability/AvailabilityController_get";
 
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL_STRING);
 var json = response.getContentText();
 var data = JSON.parse(json);

 var checkindate = data.contents.
}
```

Comment: this url doesn't provide any json!

Comment: Hello Mike, Can you guide me about this?

Comment: this is not the right place, go to https://avirato.com/blog/ and ask them for helping you using this api

Answer (score 1):

Simply writing UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL_STRING) will not do here.
you will need to put options parameter UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL_STRING,options) where options is an object such as

```
{
Content-Type: "application/json",
header:{
authorization: "basic " +API_KEY
}
accept:"application/json"
}
```